# Php upload / manage greek filenames

Tags: php, file-upload, file-management, file-manager

I am trying to build intranet app with php and mySql on Xammp. My main goal is to manage huge file directory / subdirectories which are located on windows server. All filenames are containing greek and mix greek/english words. It seems that no matter which filemanager I use (elFinder, eXtplorer etc) all have the same problem. They can't handle greek filenames. Meaning while uploading they trasliterate them with "UTF8" encoding producing unreadable filenames on windows. I know that windows default encoding is "iso-8859-7". So, my question is does and mySql on Xammp can handle this task or should I move e.g. to ASP.NET.

Comment: You can probably set PHP and MySQL to use things other than UTF8 but it will cause many headaches along the way.

Comment: I'd suggest having a script (function) that will rename all incoming files as per day and time of day.

Comment: Yep this is true, but since this is dedicated app I need build it around existing environment. Also renaming files incoming and existent currently is not an option due to more than 1TB data (doc,xls,cad etc)

Comment: ok, too bad though. Well, hopefully someone will come up with a solution for you Jim.

Comment: It's not really a mySQL and XAMPP issue, as you correctly point out it's the transliteration that the respective applications seem to be doing the wrongway. You'd have to find the right spot in the app and do an `iconv()` before the file name is `urlencode()`d.